# Set default value to dropdown if null - jquery

Tags: jquery

A very easy one but i find it very difficult.I have one drop down in which values generated at runtime.

```
  <select id="cmbCitySub" name="cmbCitySub" multiple="multiple">
         <asp:Literal ID="litCitySub" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
  </select>
```

I have used jquery multiselect plugin in drop down.

```
$('#cmbCitySub').multiselect({
    noneSelectedText: 'Select CitySub',
    selectedList: 1,
    multiple: false
}).multiselectfilter();
```

My above drop down is optional i.e. if user doesnt select any value default 0 should be set . i have tried it in jquery BUT FAILED...!!

```
if ($('#cmbCitySub').val() == null) 
     {
     $('#cmbCitySub').val('0');
     }
var sCitySub = $('#cmbCitySub').val();
alert(sCitySub);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(document.getElementById('cmbCitySub').selectedIndex == -1)
var sCitySub = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code.

```
  if($('#cmbCitySub option').length == 0)
      {
        $("#cmbCitySub").html("<option value='0'>No Value</option>");
        $("#cmbCitySub").val(0);
        alert($("#cmbCitySub").val());
      }
```

Comment: Doent Work in alert null is printing

Answer (score 0):

Since no value has been given for the default value 'Select Citysub', the value field will be empty

So, try a check like this:

```
if($.trim($('#cmbCitySub').val()) == '')
{
$('#cmbCitySub').val('0');
}
```

Comment: inside alert box [Object] [object]

Answer (score 0):

```
Check the value of DropDown in doccument load of your page like this.
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('No of Options Present in the Dropdown :' + $('#cmbCitySub option').length);
        if ($('#cmbCitySub option').length == 0) {
            $("#cmbCitySub").html("<option value='0'>No Value</option>");  
            $("#cmbCitySub").val(0);  
            alert('Current Value:' + $("#cmbCitySub").val());
        }
    });

</script>
```